# How to detect if WP7 phone is roaming

Tags: windows-phone-7

AFAIK the `IsCellularDataRoamingEnabled` property indficates if the connection supports roaming as such.

But can I find out if the phone is currently in roaming or in home network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`NetworkInterfaceInfo.Characteristics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.networkinterfaceinfo.characteristics%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) property to determine whether the phone is roaming.